# How to test WPF Bing Maps using Coded UI Test Automation?

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, coded-ui-tests

### What I am trying to do:

Use Coded UI Test Automation to assert features about a WPF application's Bing Map. Specifically, I need  to find the name and coordinates of pushpins that have already been added to the Bing Map.
[Bing Map with custom pushpin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25wAJ.png)

### What I have tried:

I have referenced https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx for working with WPF Bing Maps, however it only appears to development focused.

I have also tried using the following code to find all children controls of the WPF Custom Control (bing map).

```
WpfCustom mapView = uiMap.UIMapView.UIMap;
UITestControlCollection mapChildren = mapView.GetChildren();
```

Comment: What happens when you look into the children?  Also, does the inspector give any feedback to the stuff inside?  Or even record and playback?

Comment: The children include several controls, unfortunately not the ones we are looking for. It looks like the only solution is going to be to expose some of the properties in the application being tested so that the pins can be accessed via automation.